# TextInput align text on top on multiline={false} (with height)

Tags: ios, react-native

I am forced to use `multiline={false}` and set the height of TextInput in order to show it like it is a text area. Reason is that `multiline={true}` doesn't work very well with KeyboardAvoidingView (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16826).

So here is a simple code:

```
<TextInput placeholder="Input text here..." style={{height: 200}} multiline={false} />
```

and the output is: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX1OK.jpg)

I just want to make it the text align at the top. Works properly with Android though

Comment: just apply `paddingTop:0`

Answer (score -1):

Set style property `textAlignVertical` to `top` on the `TextInput`

```
<TextInput ... multiline={true} textAlignVertical: 'top' />
```

Comment: textAlignVertical works only in Android but not in iOS

Comment: Try adding prop `multiline={true}` in TextInput should work as I have updated my answer too